# Making Power Bi - R (HTMLwidgets pbiviz based) custom visuals interactive with other Power BI visuals

Tags: powerbi, plotly, histogram, htmlwidgets, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have made a pbiviz custom visual using developer tools of Normal distribution curve over a Histogram plot with R - ggplot2 and plotly libraries in a pbiviz.package

The visual works fine. Now I want to add interactivity of the Histogram with other Power BI visuals.
i.e. If user clicks on a bar of the Histogram, it should filter out a Table on my PBI report with rows relevant to the histogram bar data.
Considering the limitations of using R script with Power BI, I do not know if it is possible with my current visual as I am new to scripting.

Is there a better way (Typescript, JS, Python, etc.) other than what I have done to make an Interactive Histogram & Distribution Curve in Power BI?

```
This is the R script along with sample data and Visual Image

Histogram represents the projects falling in different durations

There are two bell curves - One for closed projects and Other for Active Projects
```

[image]

[image]

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

############### Library Declarations ###############
libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
libraryRequireInstall("plotly");
libraryRequireInstall("tidyverse");
libraryRequireInstall("scales");
libraryRequireInstall("htmlwidgets");

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(plotly)

theme_set(theme_bw())

##### Making DataSet for All Selected Projects #####

Duration <- dataset$Duration

Status <- (rep(dataset$ProjectStatus))

da <- data.frame(Duration,Status)
lenx <- length(Duration)

meanall <- mean(da$Duration)
sdx <- sd(da$Duration)

binwidth <- 30

font_label <- list(family = "Segoe UI", size = 21, colour = "black")
hovlabel <- list(bordercolor = "black", font = font_label)

#Filtering Out Closed Projects from Dataset
#Creating Data Frame for Closed Projects

closedproj <- dataset %>%
  select(Duration,ProjectStatus) %>%
  filter(ProjectStatus == "Closed")

closed <- closedproj$Duration
df <- data.frame(closed)


xclosed <- closedproj$
df2 <- data.frame(xclosed)
lenc <- length(xclosed)
mean_closed <- mean(df2$xclosed)
sdc <- sd(df2$xclosed)

a <- 
(ggplot(da,aes(x=Duration, fill = Status, text = paste("Duration: ",x,"-", x + binwidth,"<br />Project Count", ..count..)))+

#Histogram
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count..),alpha=0.5, position='identity',binwidth = binwidth)+


# #Distribution Curve
 annotate(
    geom = "line",
    x = da$Duration,
    y = dnorm(da$Duration, mean = meanall, sd = sdx) * lenx * binwidth,
    width = 3,
    color = "red"
    ) +

 annotate(
    geom = "line",
    x = df2$xclosed,
    y = dnorm(df2$xclosed, mean = mean_closed, sd = sdc)* lenc * binwidth,
    width = 3,
    color = "blue"
    ) +

  labs(
    x = "Project Duration (Days)", 
    y = "Project_Count",
    fill = "Project Status")+

#Mean
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=meanall),color="red",linetype="dashed",size = 0.8,label=paste("Mean :",round(meanall,0)))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean_closed),color="blue",linetype="dashed",size = 0.8,label=paste("Mean (Closed):",round(mean_closed,0)))+

# 1 Sigma
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = (meanall + sdx)), color = "red", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = (meanall - sdx)), color = "red", size = 1, linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = (mean_closed + sdc)), color = "blue", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = (mean_closed - sdc)), color = "blue", size = 1, linetype = "dashed")+


# Theme
  theme(
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  legend.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgray"),
  axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "Black",size = 18,face = "bold"),
  axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "Black",size = 18,face = "bold"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "Black",size = 15),
  axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "Black",size = 15),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+

scale_x_continuous(labels = comma,
                   breaks = seq(0, max(Duration),50)) +

scale_y_continuous(labels = comma,
                   breaks = seq(0,max(Duration),10)))

############# Create and save widget ###############
p = ggplotly(a, tooltip = c("text")) %>%
style(hoverlabel = hovlabel) %>%
 layout(legend = list(
      orientation = "h",
      x = 0,
      y = 1.13,
      title = list(text = "Project Status",font = list(family = "Segoe UI", size = 23)),
      font = font_label
      ),
  yaxis = list(title = list(standoff = 25L)),
  xaxis = list(title = list(standoff = 25L)),
  
  annotations = list(showarrow=FALSE,align = "left",valign = "top",x = 0.95, xref = "paper",yref = "paper",y = 0.955,
  font = list(family = "Segoe UI", size = 22, color = "#cc0000"),
  text = paste("Max Duration:  ", comma(round(max(da$Duration),0)),
  "<br>Mean (Closed): ", comma(round(mean_closed,0)),
  "<br>Mean (All) : ", comma(round(meanall,0))))
  ) %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c("select2d","hoverClosestCartesian", "lasso2d","hoverCompareCartesian","toggleSpikelines"), displaylogo = FALSE);

  internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
}
####################################################

################ Reduce paddings ###################
ReadFullFileReplaceString('out.html', 'out.html', ',"padding":[0-5]*,', ',"padding":0,')
```

What I expect is -- If user clicks on a bar of the Histogram, it should reflect on a Table visual on my PBI report with rows relevant to the histogram bar data.
Any help will be highly appreciated !

Regards